# Apple USB keyboard MB110B/B won't connect to MBP 2021 - is it supported?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb

I'm looking to use my beloved Apple USB keyboard MB110B/B with a 2021 MacBook Pro.

However, it's not being recognised by the laptop, when plugging it in. I'm using a Sandstrøm Multi-adapter.

What I know already:

- Keyboard works with USB-A
- Keyboard works with the same adapter on 2017 MacBook Pro
- External disk works with the same adapter on the 2021 MBP

Tried restarting and starting in safe mode.

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks

Felix

Comment: I have had good experiences with the [Anker PowerExpand Direct 7-in-2 USB-C](https://www.amazon.de/Anker-PowerExpand-Thunderbolt-Datentransfer-Speicherkartensteckplatz/dp/B07YZ48HCT/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=R5YNKWCPYIBL&keywords=anker+usb+c+hub&qid=1638806133&sprefix=anker+usb%2Caps%2C179&sr=8-5) Hub.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelS. - just to confirm: are you saying that my existing adapter, though it works with the keyboard on MBP 2017 USB-C, won't work on the MBP 2021?

Comment: No, I am not. I just wanted to give you my experience what adapter works for me.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be 100% sure: Are you using Apple USB keyboard MB110B/B with a 2021 MacBook Pro and that adapter?

Comment: So it looks like it was the adapter after all. Using the Apple USB-C to USB Adapter it works like a charm. Thanks again.